# How do I add a song to itunes using Applescript and make a vote for it?

Tags: itunes

Since iTunes 8.1 has iTunes DJ I want to be able to upload songs from one of my computers to another that runs iTunes 8.1, and add these to the Library on iTunes. After that, I want to make that song the next song in iTunes, but only if no other song has been "requested" more times through the Apple Remote application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doug's AppleScripts for iTunes has a script called [Play Album Next In Party Shuffle](http://dougscripts.com/itunes/scripts/ss.php?sp=playalbumnextinps). It seems like a good jumping-off point. iTunes DJ and Party Shuffle are apparently the same thing as far as scripts are concerned.